# OpenCV4 and Android Studio camera integration

Tags: android-studio, opencv

I am trying to create an app in android studio that opens up the camera. The problem I am facing is that the app displays black screen even after the permission of camera is granted. My app will then be used to detect emotion using a deep learning model. I am new to android development, and I know very little of what I am actually doing. I am basically copy pasting which supposedly might be an older code which doesn't work anymore. I have used the latest version of android studio as of now and successfully integrated OpenCV 4 libraries.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.opencvint;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d("MainActivity: ","Opencv is loaded");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("MainActivity: ","Opencv failed to load");
        }
    }

    private Button camera_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        camera_button=findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        camera_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

CameraActivity.java

```
package com.example.opencvint;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{
    private static final String TAG="MainActivity";

    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback =new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status){
                case LoaderCallbackInterface
                        .SUCCESS:{
                    Log.i(TAG,"OpenCv Is loaded");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                }
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public CameraActivity(){
        Log.i(TAG,"Instantiated new "+this.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA=0;
        // if camera permission is not given it will ask for it on device
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CameraActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        mOpenCvCameraView=(CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.frame_surface);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            //if load success
            Log.d(TAG,"Opencv initialization is done");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
        else{
            //if not loaded
            Log.d(TAG,"Opencv is not loaded. try again");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_4_0,this,mLoaderCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView !=null){
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mOpenCvCameraView !=null){
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
        }

    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width ,int height){
        mRgba=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mGray =new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }
    public void onCameraViewStopped(){
        mRgba.release();
    }
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();

        return mRgba;

    }

}
```

activity_camera.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_surface"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.OpenCVInt"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```